# Failing authentication in MVC pipeline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

Given that the FormsAuthentication module fires before a custom http module that handles the OnAuthenticateRequest, I'm curious if one can cancel or invalidate the forms authentication based on my own criteria.

Basically I have a process where the user logs in. After that they get a token. I get the token back after the forms authentication fires upon subsequent requests. What I want to do is then validate that the token hasn't expired against our back end server. If it's expired I need to do something so that they are forced to log back in. My thought was to do something in my OnAuthenticateRequest handler that would get picked up later in the pipeline and force a redirect back to login page or something. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

In an ASP.NET MVC application in order to handle custom Authentication and Authorization people usually write custom `Authorize` attributes. They don't deal with any `OnAuthenticateRequest` events. That's old school. And by the way if you are going to be doing some custom token authentication why even care about Forms Authentication? Why not replace it?

So:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string token = GetTokenFromHttpContext(httpContext);
        if (IsTokenValid(token))
        {
            // The user has provided a valid token => you need to set the User property
            // Obviously here based on the token value you already know which is the
            // associated user and potential roles, so you could do additional checks

            var identity = new GenericIdentity("john.smith");
            var user = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[0]);
            httpContext.User = user;

            return true;
        }

        // Notice that here we are never calling the base AuthorizeCore method
        // but you could call it if needed 

        return false;
    }

    private string GetTokenFromHttpContext(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // TODO: you know what to do here: get the token from the current HTTP Context
        // depending on how the client passed it in: HTTP request header, query string parameter, cookie, ...
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private bool IsTokenValid(string token)
    {
        // TODO: You know what to do here: go validate the token
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is to decorate your controllers/actions with this custom attribute instead of using the default one:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    // if you get that far you could use the this.User property
    // to access the currently authenticated user
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible?

This is definitely possible. You could even set your autehtication scheme to `None` so that forms module isn't there in the pipeline and have only your own module.

However, even if forms is there, your custom module can override the identity set for the current request. Note also that until the forms cookie is issued, forms module doesn't set the identity. This was quite common to use both forms module and the `SessionAuthenticationModule` - forms does the job of redirecting to the login page and the session auth module handles its own authentication cookie.

This means that you can safely mix the two: the forms module and your own custom module for a similar scenario.

Darin suggests another approach and this of course is valid too. An advantage of an authentication module (versus the authentication filter) is that the authentication module could support other ASP.NET subsystems (web forms / wcf / webapi).